# When the innerHTML is modified, why does it seem like the element is replaced in the debugger console?

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-devtools

With the following code, inside of Google Chrome's dev tool, it shows as if `root2` is changing every second, but `root2` should stay the same. If we say, it is the content of `root2` that is changing, then the content of `root1` is also updating too, but it is not flashing every second. Why is that?

```js
setInterval(function() {

  document.getElementById('root2').innerHTML = ("<h1>Hello, world!</h1><h2>" +
    new Date().toLocaleTimeString() + "</h2>");

}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="root1">
  <div id="root2"></div>
</div>
```

#### `root2` is flashing every second:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Because it is.

Using `innerHtml` assignment literally throws away "everything in this node" and bootstraps *new* child nodes based on the HTML string you used. Those new nodes might use exactly the same attributes as before, but they're still completely new nodes.

However, when using `innerHTML` you're only changing node *child content*. Not the node itself. So that's why `root1` doesn't show anything changing: none of its children got remove/added. The `root2` node did get its child content changes, so it'll signal something changed.

If you want to preserve the nodes and just update them, don't use `innerHTML`. In fact, kind of don't use `innerHTML` at all, ever, unless you *really* know what you're doing. It's almost never the solution to whatever problem or thing you're trying to solve/implement.

In this specific case, where it looks like you just want to update the active DOM based on "a newly composed string that reflects an updated DOM state", have a look at something like [morphDOM](https://github.com/patrick-steele-idem/morphdom).

Comment: it is replaced?  If I do `e = document.getElementById('root2')` in console and 10 seconds later do `e === document.getElementById('root2')` it is still showing `true`  (that was tried in a simple HTML file on hard drive, not the Snippet here or JSFiddle, so the `e` really is an element obtained, (vs in the Snippet or JSFiddle you can't get the element from the iframe easily))

Comment: `innerHTML` throws away _everything_ in the node you're setting `innerHTML` on. DOM nodes, JS event bindings, etc. etc. and then build a new DOM tree. I can't speak to how equality is evaluated, but I would be surprised if that equality holds. Got something that verifies this?

Comment: You are right, it *throws away "everything **in** this node"*, not the node itself, only its content.

Answer (score 0):

Because they do highlight the parent node of any node that got removed:

```js
const sentence = 'click to remove last text node';
root2.append.apply(root2, [...sentence]);

onclick = e => {
  lastNode = root2.childNodes[ root2.childNodes.length - 1 ];
  if(lastNode) lastNode.remove();
};
```

```html
<div id="root1">
  <div id="root2"></div>
</div>
```

They also do highlight any node that becomes a parentNode, as they do highlight any collapsed node where a new node is added:

```js
(async function loop() {
  root2.append("first node insertion highlights the new parentNode");
  await wait(1000);
  // removal does too, as shown in previous snippet
  [...root2.childNodes].forEach(node => node.remove());
  await wait(1000);
  loop();
})();

function wait(ms) { return new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms)); }
```

```html
<div id="root1">
  <div id="root2"></div>
</div>
```

So when you change you change the `innerHTML` of your Element, both these situations will happen:

- first all its content is removed => highlight,
- then your Element becomes a parentNode (again) => highlight.